# Illustrator CS2 not saving CMYK values

Tags: adobe-illustrator, cmyk

I'm using Illustrator CS2, and my document is 8bit CMYK.

I saved an AI file with black composed as 100%, 100%, 100%, 100%:

[image]

I saved it with these options:

[image]

If I open it again and use the Eyedropper Tool to inspect the black area, values are not the same I saved:

[image]

Why? Is there a special settings that makes Illustrator save color codes instead of replacing them with default ones?

Note: I know that CMYK black should be 0%,0%,0%,100% but the machine I use for printing requires everything set to 100%, otherwise it will print sort of a dark gray, not black.

Comment: Have you tried turning off the ICC profile when saving?

Comment: Yes, I tried both options in that dialog, it didn't help

Comment: I duplicated your steps and everything is fine. Try to rasterise (only if your design is all black) in bitmap mode, this will give you a pure black.

Comment: Could you identify the machine you use for printing that requires everything set to 100%?

Answer (score 1):

This is done to *save you* from yourself.

In *most* instances you **never** want to use 100C/100M/100Y/100K to color *anything*. A commercial printer can't print 100% of all colors. It's too much ink. So Illustrator *may* adjust the color to the maximum ink limit based upon color settings and preference settings.

If you need 100% of all plates, use the `Registration` swatch in Illustrator. That will maintain appearance.

In addition... check the **Preferences**. Specifically the `Appearance of Black` preference. Ensure **both** those options are set to "**Accurately**" and *not* "Rich Black" (which is the stupid default setting).

Answer (score 0):

Why?

You're doing and undoing the same thing.

In the Options, you want an embedded ICC profile to be used which overrides your double black percentages that you specify in the Picker.

As soon as you save your document, the ICC profile settles the conflicting data.

100% C + 100% M + 100% Y = 100% B (in theory). In reality, the ICC profile limits the Total Ink Coverage to be less for practical reasons.

For examples: The paper can only hold so much ink, the ink can't stick to the wet surface of the previous coat, etc.